# Logged in React page shows login page for a fraction of a second

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am new to React/Redux. I am trying to follow along this tutorial in Youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=unr4s3jd9qA). Everything is working as done in the video. However, when I refresh the page when logged in as a user, the login screen flashes for a fraction of a second before redirecting to the home screen. I have been trying to find a solution for this for 2 days. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the auth.onAuthStateChanged function is asynchronous and is called in useEffect which runs after the first render. So you get a currentUser object after the child component already rendered. I don't know firebase but what you can try is this:

```
const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(firebase.auth().currentUser);
```

But I don't think that `firebase.auth().currentUser` is synchronous so currentUser would be still `null` at initialisation;

Next you could try to differentiate the states "user state unknow aka not yet called" vs "user not logged in" and don't render something if state is unknown. This should work:

```
const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(false);

useEffect(...);

if (currentUser === false) {
  return null;
}

return (...);
```

You always have this kind of problem if you don't do server side rendering. Look at for example [nextjs](https://nextjs.org/). It's an easy solution for SSR.